# Adjust EditText icon away from the left border

Tags: android, android-edittext

I created an `EditText` with a `drawable` image. The problem is that the image is very close to the border of the `EditText`, is there a way to adjust it?

Note: Im using an svg file for the image

Image: In the image you can see the shoulder of the person is almost touching the left border

[image]

Code:

```
        <EditText

            android:id="@+id/sampleName"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/sampleImage"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"

            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `android:padding` to the `EditText` along with the `android:drawablePadding`

Comment: oh god im so stupid ive been searching for hours just for this line thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome...!!! some times it happens to developers. Please Accept the answer if it works!!

Answer (score 1):

Removing Below Line from your code will solve the problem :

```
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `android:padding="5dp"` . It will work .

Answer (score 0):

You can use **drawablePadding** and **padding**to give space to the image. Try it like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sampleName"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/sampleImage"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<EditText   
     android:id="@+id/sampleName"
     android:drawableStart="@drawable/sampleImage"
     android:drawablePadding="10dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/white"
     android:padding="15dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
     />
```